# Функция getMiddle(str)

Tags: javascript

Функция возвращает если число нечетное, средний символ строки, а если четное, то средние два символа. А если в строке один символ, то возвращает её
GetMiddle():

```
function getMiddle(str) {
    if (str.length > 0 && str.length < 1000) {
        var evenOrOdd = function(number) {
            return (+number % 2) == 0?true:false;
        }
        var $evenOrOdd = evenOrOdd(str)
        if (str.length == 1) {
            return str
        } else
        if ($evenOrOdd) {
            return str[str.length / 2] + str[str.length / 2 -1]
        } else {
            return str[(str.length - 1)  / 2]
        }
    }
}
```

Тесты с нечетными она проходит, а вот с четными возвращает undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть несколько моментов:

```js
function getMiddle(str) {                         // Будем брать .length, а если дадут не строку или объект с этим свойством?
    if (str.length > 0 && str.length < 1000) {    // Лимит установили, но в случае выхода из лимита не обработали
        var evenOrOdd = function(number) {        // Отдельная функция на раз вызова и каждый вызов её заново определять?
            return (+number % 2) == 0?true:false; // Контекст подразумевает возвращения булева значения, зачем условия; возвращайте сам результат сравнения
        }
        var $evenOrOdd = evenOrOdd(str.length)    // Мы же длину хотим проверять, а не значение строки (ошибка тут)
        if (str.length == 1) {                    // В начале стоит делать это
            return str
        } else                                    // Это не ошибка, но не ставить скобки в таком месте - тимлид на ревью будет очень недоволен
        if ($evenOrOdd) {
            return str[str.length / 2] + str[str.length / 2 -1] // Стоит поменять местами выборку символов (из-за нумерации символов с нуля, str.length / 2 укажет на второй нужный символ, а str.length / 2 -1 как раз на предыдущий)
        } else {
            return str[(str.length - 1)  / 2]
        }
    }
}

console.info(getMiddle("Some"));
console.info(getMiddle("Thing"));
```

Comment: почему в случае с "Some" она выводит "mo", вместо "om"?

Comment: Да, не обратил внимания, добавил комментарий.

Comment: А зачем нужен `debugger;`?

Comment: Я уже нашел ошибку

Comment: @gil9red, Забыл вырезать из проды :)

Answer (score 2):

```
var $evenOrOdd = evenOrOdd(str.length);
```